# Camel Rest and RestController in the same project

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-camel

I have a camel rest in my project and a servlet is configured for it. At the moment I'm trying to add a regular RestController without camel. Can two types of rest be in the same project?
For example

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    rest("/dictionary/get-dictionary")
            .get()
            .param().name("dictionary").required(true).type(RestParamType.query).endParam()
            .param().name("name").required(true).type(RestParamType.query).endParam()
             .....
            .endRest();
```

CamelServlet implemented for camel

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/createOrder")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderController {
    private final OrderService OrderService;

    @PostMapping
    public void createForm(@RequestBody App app) {
        orderService.createFullOrder(app);
    }
}
```

When I request createOrder, I always get 404. How can I make both types of controllers work?
Thank in advice

Comment: The only way I can see this working is by having the RestController somehow get the Camel servlet when it is created. No idea how to achieve that though...

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
 @Configuration
    public class AppConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
            return new DispatcherServlet();
        }
    
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean axisServletRegistrationBean() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet(), "/createOrder");
            registration.addUrlMappings("/createOrder");
            return registration;
        }
    }



    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.package.package")
    public class WebConfig {
    

    }
```